# ControlValueAccessor (change) event is fired twice (Angular 4)

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a custom component (`my-custom-input`) with `ControlValueAccessor`. It works, but the change event is fired twice. The function in my component which fires the change events looks like this:

```
private myval: string;

@Input() disabled: boolean = false;
@Output() change = new EventEmitter<string>();

fireChange() {
    console.log("Change emit");
    this.change.emit(this.myval);
    console.log("Change callback");
    this.onChangeCallback(this.myval);
    console.log("Touch emit");
    this.onTouchedCallback(this.myval);
}
```

This is how I listen to changes in an other component, where I try to use `my-custom-input`:

```
<my-custom-input [(ngModel)]="this.data" (change)="vChanged()"></my-custom-input>
```

```
vChanged() {
    console.log("change", this.data);
}
```

This is what I read in the console:

```
Change emit
change "oldvalue"
Change callback
Touch emit
change "newvalue"
```

Why is the `change` callback called twice?

Comment: Is your environment is set to `production; false` ? If so, this is a normal behavior in the change detection mechanism.

Comment: Yes, it is false. Why is it a normal behaviour?

Comment: Nevermind, It 's a problem with the binding of your component as pointed (but not explained) in the @AlexandreAnnic answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
<my-custom-input [ngModel]="this.data" (change)="vChanged()"></my-custom-input>
```

Comment: You should explain your solution otherwise it can be considered as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: My component stops working if I remove the parentheses from `ngModel`

Comment: @IterAtor Please post the whole component. The error should be in it.